# Touchpad registers 'enter' when hovering over an action item on screen despite absence of a click

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I struggle to describe what's going on here.

I recently bought an HP laptop after years on a mac and discovered some behaviour in the touchpad I had not encountered before.

Some times when I am using some software where clicking leads to an action - which is almost all software let's face it - when my finger is on the touchpad and the cursor/arrow is on a part of the document where clicking causes something to happen, the software registers that I have clicked (i.e. caused the action to happen) even when I have not clicked. It's like there is a function somewhere that is 'helpfully' registering that I want to click something simply because my cursor hasn't moved. I changed the sensitivity of the touchpad to low but the problem still persists.

I really worry that this could lead to emails being sent halfway composed or poorly composed, or worse.

**Does anyone know what this behaviour is and how I might undo this setting?**

Comment: Open  *Mouse & Touchpad* settings, and turn off tap to double-click, and possibly other touchpad settings. You might also have a Settings control panel from the touchpad manufacturer, e.g. Synaptics.

Comment: Thank you. I think I misunderstood what they meant by a tap and a click.